# Combine API data with MongoDB data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm currently working on a NodeJS API that fetches data from an external API. The API also has a MongoDB with extra data that the external API does not provide.

What I'm trying to do: 
Fetch items from the external API, add the extra data saved in the MongoDB and return at as a whole.

I'm trying this:

```
HTTP.get({
    host: 'example.com',
    path: '/exam/ple',
    method: 'GET'
}, function(response){
    var body = '';
    response.on('data' , function(chunk){
        body += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function(){
        json = JSON.parse(body);
        //Attach own data with fetched data
        json.trucks.forEach(function(item){
            DB.collection(COLLECTION).findOne({"id" : example.id}, function(err, doc){
                if(!err){
                    item.extra = doc.extra;
                    item.extra2= doc.extra2;
                    console.log(truck); //Check if truck is updated
                }
            });
        });
       res.body(200).json(json);
    });
});
```

But that's not working. The body/response is the data only fetched from the API. But the data is getting merged in the foreach loop.

**UPDATE
I've added the use of 'callbacks' and the code is as follows:

```
   var getLocalStorage = function(_id , callback){
       DB.collection(COLLECTION).findOne({id : _id}), function(err,msg){
           if(!err){
               callback(null,doc)
           }
       } 
   }


HTTP.get({
        host: 'demo1757530.mockable.io',
        path: '/vrachtwagens/in',
        method: 'GET'
    }, function(response){
        var body = '';
        response.on('data' , function(chunk){
            body += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function(){
            var i = 0,
            data = JSON.parse(body);
            data.items.forEach(function(item){
                i++
                getLocalStorage(item._id, function(err,msg){
                  //MERGE DATA
                }
            });
            if(i === data.items.length){
                //return body
            }
```

But the result is still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont understand the callback paradighm in node.js. The response is sent before first request to mongo database is fired. Try to learn more about it and before you do, this is working (however not very elegant) solution

```
    json = JSON.parse(body);
    //Attach own data with fetched data
    var i=0;
    json.trucks.forEach(function(item){
        DB.collection(COLLECTION).findOne({"id" : example.id}, function(err, doc){
            i++;
            if(!err){
                item.extra = doc.extra;
                item.extra2= doc.extra2;
                console.log(truck); //Check if truck is updated
            }
            if (i === json.trucks.length){
                 res.body(200).json(json);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You're right, never worked with nodejs before.. I know it's not elegant, but could not find any other way to achieve this result. Thanks a lot for your help!